# HTML Form action that stays on the current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I'm making a newsletter signup, a user inputs their email and clicks the form submit button. The problem is that the newsletter signup is in my footer, which shows up on every page of the website. Right now I have the action="newsletter.php" which sends me an email with the email they used to sign up. I could have a "window.location=""" but I wanted it to go back to the page they came from (because the footer could've been on any page of the website).

Now, I'm wondering if there's a way to NOT have the form action be "newsletter.php", and instead have the php just be inside the footer file, so that they never even leave the page they were on in the first place, a simple window.alert can just let them know their sign up was successful and they can keep doing what they were doing no matter what page of the website they were on.

After getting idea's from google and trying on my own, I tried making a javascript function that contained the php needed to send me an email with the email they type in but then it was obviously sending me a blank email every time any page of the website loaded. I also tried doing "isset" but the problem with that is the action="" just reloads the page before the isset can check if they typed in an email.

NEWSLETTER.PHP-

```
   <?php
$field_emailInput = $_POST['emailInput'];

$mail_to = 'josh@cutephilosophy.com';
$subject = 'NEWSLETTER SUBSCRIBER';

$body_message .= 'This person subscribed for email updates: ';
$body_message .= 'E-Mail: '.$field_emailInput."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_emailInput."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_emailInput."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.alert('You Are Now In The Loop!');
        //window.location = 'index.php';
        window.location ='history.back()';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Something broke, email josh@cutephilosophy.com about the problem!');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

You'll notice I tried "history.back()" when using the action="newsletter.php" method, this works, but while the window.alert is shown you are on a complete white page instead of the page they were initially on, and then you are redirected back.

Comment: If I submitted a form for signing up to a newsletter, I'd expect to see a confirmation page so that I knew it had worked. After that, most people are quite capable of clicking their browser's back button.

Comment: If you don't want them to leave the page at all you need to use AJAX.

Comment: You don't *need* Ajax, you can use an HTTP 204 No Content response instead. Still a poor idea to not give feedback though.

Comment: Quentin, as far as user experience goes, I don't think a new page would be desirable, that could risk losing viewers that just leave because they feel they've "finished" their business there. I'd rather just show a popup saying it worked so they can get right back to what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use PHP_Self. Or add in a back button to your html to allow them to click back to where they were.

Comment: A back button is too much work, I want them to stay on the page they were on and just have a simple popup saying their signup was successful.

Elaborate on how I would incorporate PHP_Self?

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/362703/executing-php-script-without-leaving-the-page

Answer (score 0):

Use php `mail()` to send the email and set the form action to

`htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

The htmlspecialcharacters part adds security to your form, while the server part returns you to the same page.